# How to display interactively percentages in d3?

Tags: d3.js, graph

I'm trying to display the percentages of a polygonal shape within a radar graph by hovering on its name in the legend.

Here is a pic: [image]

You can see that the first brand name is being hovered over in the legend and that the corresponding polygonal shape in the graph is selected as a result. I'd like the shape to be surrounded by its values (in %) at each of its angles.

I wrote this code that puts all the percentages at the right places and set their `opacity` to `0`

```
// percentages
                    var pourcents = g.selectAll(".pourcentage")
                                   .data(data)
                                   .enter()
                                   .append("g")
                                   .attr("class","pourcentage");


                          pourcents.selectAll(".pourcentagetext")
                                   .data(function(d,i) {return d[1]})
                                   .enter().append("text")          
                                   .text(function (d,i) { if (d.value == 0) {"fill", "none"} else {return Format(d.value)}})
                                   .attr("x", function(d,i){ return rScale(d.value + 0.05)* Math.cos(angleSlice*i - Math.PI/2) })
                                   .attr("y", function(d,i){ return rScale(d.value + 0.05) * Math.sin(angleSlice*i - Math.PI/2) })
                                   .attr("class", "pourcentagetext")
                                   .attr("id", function (d,i) {return "per" + i})
                                   .style("font-size", 10)
                                   .style("opacity", 0);
```

How can I select a group of percentages corresponding to a specific shape and make them appear with it ?

Edit: the code for the polygonal shapes:

```
blobWrapper.append("path")
                           .attr("class", "radarArea")
                           .attr("d", function(d,i) { return radarLine(d[1])})
                           .style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(i); })
                           .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea)
                           .attr("id", function (d,i) {return "tag" + i})
```

I operate the selection and make them appear by setting an `id`:

```
legende.on("mouseover", function(d, i, j) {d3.select("#tag" + i)
                                                          .transition()
                                                          .duration(100)
                                                          .style("fill-opacity", 1);
```

How can I do the same type of selection but with a group of corresponding percentages ?

Comment: If the indices are the same, its just `d3.select("#per"+i).transition().duration(100).style("fill-opacity", 1)`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @GerardoFurtado. That's actually what I initially wrote but this displays the percentages one by one (not by group) for each brand name that i hover over. So if I hover over the 5 first brand names with the mouse, i'll get the 5 first percentages of the first brand. I really don't know how to select the whole **group** of percentages corresponding to a specific polygonal shape (here `blobWrapper`).

Comment: Why don't you share a **working** code? Fiddle, Plunker, whatever... That way it will be easier to see what you've got right now and how to change it.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I tried so many times to create one on JSFiddle to share it here, but I don't know hot to make it work. It's just plain code, it's really frustrating. If you could give me a hint on what I should fix to make it work, it would be amazing. I'm a total beginner, so please bear with me. Here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/72r9janr/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice chart you have

> How can I do the same type of selection but with a group of
>   corresponding percentages ?

i said earlier you can add a class, select that class using

> `d3.selectAll(/*class_name*/).each(function(){})`

then do something on each of that

> if you using `d3.select('id')` you just select one element

that its why it work on `path`, not on `text` with using `#per1,#per2 etc` what its that? why you not name it with same class or group it?

see this. i hope you will understand

```js
var data = [
            [[{name: "Bonpoint"}], [
                {axis: "Coton", value: 1},
                {axis: "Laine", value: 0.8},
                {axis: "Cachemire", value: 0.6},
                {axis: "Soie", value: 0.20},
                {axis: "Angora", value: 0.20},
                {axis: "Autres", value: 0.20},
                {axis: "Nylon", value: 0},
                {axis: "Acrylique", value: 0},
                {axis: "Viscose", value: 0},
                {axis: "Polyuréthane", value: 0},
                {axis: "Polyester", value: 0.20}]],

            [[{name: "Petit Bateau"}], [
                {axis: "Coton", value: 1},
                {axis: "Laine", value: 0.40},
                {axis: "Cachemire", value: 0},
                {axis: "Soie", value: 0},
                {axis: "Angora", value: 0},
                {axis: "Autres", value: 0},
                {axis: "Nylon", value: 0},
                {axis: "Acrylique", value: 0},
                {axis: "Viscose", value: 0},
                {axis: "Polyuréthane", value: 0},
                {axis: "Polyester", value: 0.20}]],

            [[{name: "Bobo Choses"}], [
                {axis: "Coton", value: 1},
                {axis: "Laine", value: 0.20},
                {axis: "Cachemire", value: 0},
                {axis: "Soie", value: 0},
                {axis: "Angora", value: 0},
                {axis: "Autres", value: 0},
                {axis: "Nylon", value: 0.40},
                {axis: "Acrylique", value: 0.40},
                {axis: "Viscose", value: 0},
                {axis: "Polyuréthane", value: 0},
                {axis: "Polyester", value: 0}]],

            [[{name: "BeBe"}], [
                {axis: "Coton", value: 0.40},
                {axis: "Laine", value: 0},
                {axis: "Cachemire", value: 0},
                {axis: "Soie", value: 0},
                {axis: "Angora", value: 0},
                {axis: "Autres", value: 0},
                {axis: "Nylon", value: 0.20},
                {axis: "Acrylique", value: 0.80},
                {axis: "Viscose", value: 0.40},
                {axis: "Polyuréthane", value: 0},
                {axis: "Polyester", value: 0.80}]],

            [[{name: "Familiar"}], [
                {axis: "Coton", value: 1},
                {axis: "Laine", value: 0.20},
                {axis: "Cachemire", value: 0},
                {axis: "Soie", value: 0},
                {axis: "Angora", value: 0},
                {axis: "Autres", value: 0},
                {axis: "Nylon", value: 0},
                {axis: "Acrylique", value: 0},
                {axis: "Viscose", value: 0},
                {axis: "Polyuréthane", value: 0},
                {axis: "Polyester", value: 0.40}]],

            [[{name: "Miki House"}], [
                {axis: "Coton", value: 1},
                {axis: "Laine", value: 0},
                {axis: "Cachemire", value: 0},
                {axis: "Soie", value: 0},
                {axis: "Angora", value: 0},
                {axis: "Autres", value: 0},
                {axis: "Nylon", value: 0},
                {axis: "Acrylique", value: 0},
                {axis: "Viscose", value: 0},
                {axis: "Polyuréthane", value: 0},
                {axis: "Polyester", value: 0.40}]],

            [[{name: "Uniqlo"}], [
                {axis: "Coton", value: 1},
                {axis: "Laine", value: 0.20},
                {axis: "Cachemire", value: 0},
                {axis: "Soie", value: 0},
                {axis: "Angora", value: 0},
                {axis: "Autres", value: 0},
                {axis: "Nylon", value: 0},
                {axis: "Acrylique", value: 0.20},
                {axis: "Viscose", value: 0},
                {axis: "Polyuréthane", value: 0.20},
                {axis: "Polyester", value: 0.40}]],

            [[{name: "Baby GAP"}], [
                {axis: "Coton", value: 1},
                {axis: "Laine", value: 0},
                {axis: "Cachemire", value: 0},
                {axis: "Soie", value: 0},
                {axis: "Angora", value: 0},
                {axis: "Autres", value: 0},
                {axis: "Nylon", value: 0},
                {axis: "Acrylique", value: 0.20},
                {axis: "Viscose", value: 0},
                {axis: "Polyuréthane", value: 0.20},
                {axis: "Polyester", value: 0.40}]],

            [[{name: "Lucien Zazou"}], [
                {axis: "Coton", value: 0.80},
                {axis: "Laine", value: 0},
                {axis: "Cachemire", value: 0},
                {axis: "Soie", value: 0},
                {axis: "Angora", value: 0},
                {axis: "Autres", value: 0},
                {axis: "Nylon", value: 0},
                {axis: "Acrylique", value: 0.20},
                {axis: "Viscose", value: 0.20},
                {axis: "Polyuréthane", value: 0},
                {axis: "Polyester", value: 0.60}]],

            ];


        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["#00baff", "#0014fe", "#00ff9c", "#f4bf02", "#ffa600", "#ff0000", "#ff00c4", "#ee693e", "#99958f"]);



        radarChart(".radarChart", data);



function radarChart(id, data, options) 
                    {
                      var cfg = {w: 700,
                          h: 700,
                          margin: {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
                          levels: 5,
                          labelFactor: 1.35,
                          wrapWidth: 60,
                          opacityArea: 0.2,
                          dotRadius: 2,
                          opacityCircles: 0.1,
                          strokeWidth: 1,
                          roundStrokes: true,
                          areaName: "areaName",
                          ratio: 1.8,
                           
                          color:function(d){
                            return 'black'
                          }
                                }

                    if('undefined' !== typeof options) 
                          {for(var i in options)
                            {if ('undefined' !== typeof options[i]){cfg[i] = options[i]} } }


                     
                    var maxValue = d3.max(data, function(i){return d3.max(i[1].map(function(o) 
                                                  {return o.value}))} ); 

                    var minValue = d3.min(data, function(i) {return d3.min(i[1].map(function(o) {return o.value}))});

      

                   var areaName = cfg["areaName"];

                    // Variables for when creating the axis
                    var allAxis = (data[0][1].map(function(i, j) {return i.axis})),
                        total = allAxis.length, // autant d'axes que d''axis' indiqués dans data
                        radius = (cfg.h/3), //rayon du cercle le plus éloigné
                        innerRadius = (radius / cfg.levels) * cfg.ratio,
                        Format = d3.format('.0%'), //affiche en pourcentage, arrondi à l'entier
                        angleSlice = Math.PI * 2 / total; // L'écart entre chaque part de camembert




                    // Radius scale
                    var rScale =d3.scaleLinear().range([innerRadius,radius]).domain([0,maxValue]);


                    // Svg
                    var svg = d3.select("body")
                          .append("svg")
                          .attr("width", cfg.w + cfg.margin.left + cfg.margin.right)
                          .attr("height", cfg.h + cfg.margin.top + cfg.margin.bottom)
                          .attr("class", "radar");

   
                    // g
                    var g = svg.append("g")
                               .attr("transform", "translate(" + (cfg.w/2 + cfg.margin.left) + "," + (cfg.h/2 - cfg.margin.top) + ")");




                // GRID
                var axisGrid = g.append("g").attr("class", "axisWrapper");

                // Grid variables
                var inconnu = 2.13 //ratio: 1.8   
                var distance =  cfg.ratio * inconnu ;
                var step = distance / (cfg.levels + 1)


                // drawing the Grid
                axisGrid.selectAll(".levels")
                        .data(d3.range(0, distance, step)) //nombres et écart (1) de cercles à partir du centre 
                        .append("circle")
                        .attr("class", "gridCircle")
                        .attr("r", function(d, i){return innerRadius + (radius /cfg.levels * d)})
                        .style("fill", "white")
                        .style("stroke", "lightgrey")
                        .style("stroke-width", 0.2)
                        .style("fill-opacity", 0);



                // Axis displaying the percentages (not displayed atm)
                    axisGrid.selectAll(".axisLabel")
                            .data(d3.range(1, cfg.levels+1)) // à partir du 2è cercle jusqau'au 5ème
                            .enter()
                            .append("text")
                            .attr("class", "axisLabel")
                            .attr("x", -10)
                            .attr("y", function(d){return innerRadius + (radius /(cfg.levels * 1.575) * d)})
                            .attr("dy", "0.4em")
                            .style("font-size", "10px")
                            .attr("fill", "#737373")
                            .text(function(d,i) { return Format((d/cfg.levels))})
                            .style("display", "none");

                


                // Drawing the axis
                    var axis = axisGrid.selectAll(".axis")
                               .data(allAxis)
                               .enter()
                               .append("g")
                               .attr("class", "axis");

                    axis.append("line")
                        .attr("x1", function(d, i){return rScale(0) * Math.cos(angleSlice*i - Math.PI/2)  }) //x du point de départ des lignes
                        .attr("y1", function(d, i){return rScale(0) * Math.sin(angleSlice*i - Math.PI/2)  }) //y du points de départ des lignes
                        .attr("x2", function(d, i){ return rScale(maxValue) * Math.cos(angleSlice*i - Math.PI/2); })
                        .attr("y2", function(d, i){ return rScale(maxValue) * Math.sin(angleSlice*i - Math.PI/2); })
                        .attr("class", "line")
                        .style("stroke", "lightgrey")
                        .style("stroke-width", 1)
                        .attr("display", "none");


                  // Legend (brand names)
                  var legende =   svg.selectAll("noms")
                                   .data(data)
                                   .enter()
                                   .append("text")
                                   .text(function(d) {return d[0].map(function (o) {return o.name})})
                                   .attr("class", "legende")
                                   .style("font-family", "helvetica")
                                   .style("fill-opacity", 0.8)
                                   .attr("x",  0)
                                   .attr("y", function (d,i) {return 12 + i * 20})
                                   .attr("id", function (d,i) {return "leg" + i})
                                   .style("font-size", 10)
                                   .style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(i)})
                                   .style("opacity", 1);




                    // Put all the percentages at the right place (opacity set to 0 atm)
                    var pourcents = g.selectAll(".pourcentage")
                                   .data(data)
                                   .enter()
                                   .append("g")
                                   .attr('class',function(d) {return d[0].map(function (o,i) {return "pourcentage"+d.name})})

                                  // .attr("class","pourcentage");

                          
                          pourcents.selectAll(".pourcentagetext")
                                   .data(function(d,i) {return d[1]})
                                   .enter().append("text")          
                                   
                                   .attr("x", function(d,i){ return rScale(d.value + 0.05)* Math.cos(angleSlice*i - Math.PI/2) })
                                   .attr("y", function(d,i){ return rScale(d.value + 0.05) * Math.sin(angleSlice*i - Math.PI/2) })
                                   .attr("id", function (d,i) {return "per" + i})
                                   .attr("class", "per" + "pct" )
                                   .style("font-size", 10)
                                    .text(function (d,i) { if (d.value == 0) {"fill", "none"} else {return Format(d.value)}})
                                   .style("opacity", 0);



                  // Drawing the lines of the blobs (polygonal shapes)
                    var radarLine = d3.radialLine()
                                   .curve(d3.curveLinearClosed)
                                   .radius(function(d) { return rScale(d.value); })
                                   .angle(function(d,i) { return i*angleSlice });
                        

    
                        if(cfg.roundStrokes) {radarLine.curve(d3.curveLinearClosed)}
          

      


                var blobWrapper = g.selectAll(".radarWrapper")
                           .data(data)
                           .enter().append("g")
                           .attr("class", "radarWrapper");
            
                //mouseover
                var m_over= function(d,i,j){        
                    d3.selectAll(".radarArea")
                                                         .transition().duration(100)
                                                         .style("fill-opacity", 0);

                                                         d3.selectAll(".radarStroke")
                                                         .transition().duration(100)
                                                         .style("stroke-width", 0);

                                                        d3.select("#tag" + i)
                                                          .transition()
                                                          .duration(100)
                                                          .style("fill-opacity", 1);
                                                        
                                                        d3.selectAll(".cir" + i)
                                                          .transition()
                                                          .duration(100)
                                                          .style("fill-opacity", 1);
                                                        d3.selectAll(".cir_txt" + i)
                                                          .transition()
                                                          .duration(100)
                                                          .style("fill-opacity", 1);

                                                        d3.select(this).style("font-size", 12);
                                                        d3.selectAll(".cir_txt" + i).each(function (d,i) {return d3.select(this).style("opacity",1)})
                                                       d3.selectAll(".cir" + i).each(function (d,i) {return d3.select(this).style("opacity",1)})
                                                        d3.select("#tag" + i).each(function (d,i) {return d3.select("#per").style("opacity", 1)})
                  
                }
                
                var m_out= function(d, i) {d3.selectAll(".radarArea")
                                                         .transition().duration(500)
                                                         .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea);

                                                         d3.selectAll(".radarStroke")
                                                         .transition().duration(500)
                                                         .style("stroke-width", 0.1);
                                                          
                                                         d3.select("#tag" + i)
                                                          .transition()
                                                          .duration(700)
                                                          .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea);
                                                          
                                                          d3.selectAll(".cir" + i).each(
                                                          function(d,i){
                                                            return d3.select(this).style("opacity",0)
                                                          }).transition()
                                                          .duration(700)
                                                          .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea)
                                                          
                                                          d3.selectAll(".cir_txt" + i).each(
                                                          function(d,i){
                                                            return d3.select(this).style("opacity",0)
                                                          }).transition()
                                                          .duration(700)
                                                          .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea)
                                                          
                                                          
                                                          
                                                        }

         
                // Drawing the blobs 
                blobWrapper.append("g")
                .attr("id", function (d,i) {return "tog" + i})
                .append("path")
                           .attr("class", "radarArea")
                           .attr("d", function(d,i) { return radarLine(d[1])})
                           .style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(i); })
                           .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea)
                           .attr("id", function (d,i) {return "tag" + i})
                           .on("mouseover",m_over)

                           .on("mouseout",m_out); 


        

                // Drawing the strokes of the blobs
                blobWrapper.append("path")
                           .attr("class", "radarStroke")
                           .attr("d", function(d,i) { return radarLine(d[1]); })
                           .style("stroke-width", 0.1)
                           .style("stroke", function(d,i) { return color(i); })
                           .style("fill", "none")
                           .attr("id", function (d,i) {return "rad" + i});   

                

  
                // Add points (small circles) at every blobs angles (not displayed atm)
 
                      
                data.forEach(function(d,i){
                  var idx = i
                d3.select("#tog" + i).selectAll(".circle")
                         .data(function(d,i,j){return d[1]})
                         .enter()
                         
                         .append('circle')
                         .attr('class', 'cir'+i )
                         
               
                         
                    
                         
                         .attr("r", cfg.dotRadius)
                         .attr("cx", function(d,i){ return rScale(d.value) * Math.cos(angleSlice*i - Math.PI/2) })
                         .attr("cy", function(d,i){ return rScale(d.value) * Math.sin(angleSlice*i - Math.PI/2); })
                         .style("fill", function(d,i,j) { if  (d.value === 0) {return "none"} else {return cfg.color(j)}}) 
                         .style("fill-opacity", 0)
                          .style("fill",  color(idx))
                  
                  d3.select("#tog" + i).selectAll("text")
                  .data(function(d,i,j) {return d[1]})
                         .enter().append("text")
                         .attr('class', 'cir_txt'+i )
                         .attr("x", function(d,i){ return rScale(d.value) * Math.cos(angleSlice*i - Math.PI/2) })
                         .attr("y", function(d,i){ return rScale(d.value) * Math.sin(angleSlice*i - Math.PI/2); })
                         .style("fill", function(d,i,j) { if  (d.value == 0) {return "none"} else {return cfg.color(j)}}) 
                         .style("fill-opacity", 1)
                          .attr("dx", -25) 
                          //.attr("dy", -10) 
                            .attr("text-anchor", "right") 
                        .style("font-weight", "bold")
                
                         .text( function(d,i,j) { if  (d.value == 0) {return "none"} else {return Format(d.value)}})
                      .style("fill-opacity", 0);
                })


                
     // Set a mouseover function for the legend
                  legende.on("mouseover",m_over)


                                                      
                          .on("mouseout",m_out);


                
                  // Add a white circle at the center, inside the inner circle
                  var centercircle = g.append("circle").attr("r", innerRadius + 1.5).raise().style("fill", "white").style("opacity", 1).style("stroke-width", 1).style("stroke", "lightgrey");


                 

                // Names of the textiles (one at the end of each axis)
                    axis.append("text")
                        .attr("class", "legend")
                        .style("font-size", "11px")
                        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
                        .attr("x", function(d, i){ return rScale(maxValue * cfg.labelFactor) * Math.cos(angleSlice*i - Math.PI/2); })
                        .attr("y", function(d, i){ return rScale(maxValue * cfg.labelFactor) * Math.sin(angleSlice*i - Math.PI/2); })
                        .text(function(d){return d})
                        .attr("id", function(d,i) {return "mat" + i});
                
                      
                     
  
}
```

```css
body {font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
          font-size: 11px;
          font-weight: 300;
          fill: #242424;
          text-align: center;
          cursor: default;}

      

        .legend {font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
               fill: #333333;}
      .tooltip {fill: #333333;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.min.js"></script>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

   

<body>
     <div class="radarChart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I apologize for the late reply. I want to say a massive thank you for your help, I'm so grateful that you took the time to take a close look at my code. I must admit I don't understand everything quite yet but it's a great opportunity for me to learn. Cheers !